# Spring-like property on MenuStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, menustrip

Is there any Spring-like property for `ToolStripMenuItem`? I've used the `Spring` property on a `ToolStripItem`?

What I want is a label to act as a separator that pushes a few buttons to the far right of a `MenuStrip`, like shown below:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________
| File | Edit | View | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx | Foo | Bar |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Instead of:

```
 ______________________________________________________________________
| File | Edit | View | Foo | Bar |                                     |
 ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾
```

Where `xxxxxx` is the spacer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [`Alignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripitem.alignment(v=vs.110).aspx) property for `ToolStripMenuItem` which is by default set to `Left`. If you set the alignment for an item to `Right` it will push the item to right side of the menu.

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! I assumed that was for text because I didn't see the `TextAlign` property! Oops!